# ASP.NET Web Site "The name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Product.aspx

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="quantitytb"></asp:textbox>
      <asp:Button CssClass="addtocart-button" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" ID="addtocartbutton" onclick="addtocartbutton_Click"></asp:Button>

   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Product.aspx.cs

```
protected void addtocartbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  quantitytb.Text="1";
}
```

Line 1 of Product.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Product.aspx.cs" Inherits="Product" %>
```

Above is just a small section of how my code looks like. Any controls I add to my Product.aspx page does not work in the .cs file. There will be an error saying "The name 'control name' does not exist in the current context". Literally tried all the solutions I can find online but to no avail.

Note that I am using ASP.Net Empty Web Site and not Web Application so there's no designer.cs file.

Comment: including the desired behavior in your question would be nice here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `quantitytb` directly because it is within a `DataList`. Similar to any data-bound container (`gridview`, `repeater`, `formview`, etc), you must target a specific item/row to find its child controls. If your datalist has 10 items in it, that means you'll have 10 occurrences of `quantitytb` - if you don't specify which one you're targeting, the code will throw an error.

If you're trying to modify the textbox that's the sibling of the clicked button, perhaps what you're looking for is this:

```
protected void addtocartbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Find the button that was clicked
  Button addToCart = (Button)sender;

  //Get the button's parent item, and within that item, look for a textbox called quantitytb
  TextBox quantitytb = (TextBox)addToCart.Parent.FindControl("quantitytb");

  //Set that textbox's text to "1"
  quantitytb.Text="1";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! However, if my datalist has more than 1 item, how do I make it such that the code target the specific item I want?

Comment: My current answer should do that. We can get the `sender` (the button that was clicked), then get its parent (the datalist item). Now that we have the specific item, we can say "In that specific item, find `quantitytb` and change its text." I've commented my code to make this more clear.

Comment: Thank you once again! It works! However, if I were to use <Input> controls instead of textboxes, what changes do I have to make to the c# code?

`<input runat="server" type="number" value="1" min="0" max="99" class="qtyinput" id="qtyinput">`

Comment: You can put `type="number"` on an `<asp:Textbox>`, actually, if that's your only reason for using `input` instead.